# Update a model field fetching data from user model in django

Tags: django, model

I have a User model using AbstractBaseUser. I have a model Employee using Model class. I want that when a user is created though sign up, the user inherits all the fields of Employee model. I have made a OnetoOne relation between User model and Employee. But after creating an user when I query employee model, I can not find any data related to the created User.
User manager:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email,username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            username=username
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            username=username
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

User:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    Creates a customized database table for user
    """
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email',]

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True
```

I have extended the user model with a OnetoOne relation using `OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)`

```
Employee model:

    class Employee(models.Model):
        """
        Create employee attributes
        """
        employee_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        e_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=False)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=128, unique=True)
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("employee:employee-list")
        @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Employee.objects.create(employee_user=instance)
        instance.Employee.save()
```

In this model there is also a field named email. I have to keep this field because I am using this model to create a form for Employee creation. But the problem is, User model's email field is conflicting with employee email field. I have to keep both the email fields.

Can I update the employee email field with user email field?? If yes, then what should be the query???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have created a custom user model soo you need to import he Auth_User_model from you setting file and than use that not the django inbuilt auth User.
You can do this

```
from django.conf import settings

employee_user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: tried this but when I see Employee table in the database, the table remains empty

Comment: well it should be empty cause you have not filled in anything. But what you want is to create the employee profile on creation. Is it?

Comment: yes. When the user is created, the user should inherit the attributes of Employee.

Comment: you could user signals for that. It can help you create employee model on creation. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

Comment: Okay let me try this

Comment: hmm!! i guess not. there is this method call post_save in signals where you can do something after the form is save. In your case u want to create the employee model after the user registers. So, this can help you achieve what you want.

Comment: if i use this, an error is giving. "Column 'e_id' cannot be null" . I have to set null=False to all of the fields, right???

Comment: just do null=True for all the fields cause it is creating the model with empty fields and thats not allowed

Comment: I can not to null=True to all the fields, because i am using this model for creating a form also. In that form there must be some required fields also.

Comment: well why do you want the id fields causer Django generated the id automatically and can be accessed anytime

Comment: I know. But that ID represents employee identity. But First name can not be null. I have to make it a required field

Comment: Hmm, you want the first and last name. So you can just create those field on registration by creating a custom user model and not using the django auth user

Comment: Actually i Have 10-15 fields in employee model